# Google Dataproc Insufficient number of DataNodes reporting

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I use the default network configurations and try to run a standard cluster with 1 master and 2 workers but it always fail. Worker nodes fails to do an RPC to master or vice-versa. I also get an info message on the cluster page notifying me that

> The firewall rules for specified network or subnetwork would likely
>   not permit sufficient VM-to-VM communication for Dataproc to function
>   properly

The error messages is as follow:

> Cannot start master: Insufficient number of DataNodes reporting Worker
>   cluster-597c-w-0 unable to register with master cluster-597c-m. This
>   could be because it is offline, or network is misconfigured. Worker
>   cluster-597c-w-1 unable to register with master cluster-597c-m. This
>   could be because it is offline, or network is misconfigured.

Though I use the default configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found there was a miss-configuration in the firewall rule, it was allowing tcp ports from 1 to 33535 so I changed it to 65535.